# Check the data of representations of Lie groups

Tags: number-representation, group-theory

Is there a way in Mathematica to check the data of representation of Lie groups? For example,

- the number of generators.
- the rank (or the dimension) of the representation matrices.
- and a list of all irreducible representations.

For example, for

the data of representation of Spin(5)?

or

the data of representation of Spin($n$) in general?

---

My attempt: One possibility is to use the LieART -- A Mathematica Application for Lie Algebras and Representation Theory

https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6379

Are there some other useful commands in Mathematica?

Comment: 1) To be clear, you want an answer *not* relying on LieART? 2) What do you mean by "*a list of all irreducible representations*"? such a list is not finite, so what output do you expect from MMA?